# Скрипт для удаление pdf файлов

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

подскажите как реализовать скрипт для удаление pdf файлов c локальных PC по OC(Windows 7) на powershell

Comment: Скрипты разных языков бывают. Советую использовать Powershell -- это уже должно быть "в коробке". А так, ваш вопрос лучше конкретизировать скриптовым языком

Comment: @gil9red, и почему на нём? На bat ничем не хуже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, первое, что пришло в голову :) А так, `bat` вариант

Comment: Разницы, ЧЕМ удалять, - нет. Что так, что так - просто. Может, какие-то условия есть?

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб удалить все PDF файлы находящиеся например в папке ***С:\Documents***:

```
remove-item c:\Documents\*.pdf
```

Знаком "*" мы указываем "все файлы" с расширением ".pdf"

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы удалить все PDF файлы находящиеся на локальном диске:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' *.pdf -Recurse | foreach { 
    Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName 
}
```